# Forge viewer - Core extensions - how to load them, standard way does not work

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I am trying to load some of the core extesions mentioned here at https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/extensions

but classic viewer.loadExtension does not do the trick. Always returns false for all of them. **Can you give me an example how I can load some other extension than just InViewerSearch** already shown in other documentation page like MarkupsCore? I tried same approach like in case of InViewerSearch on other extensions and it does not work too. Nothing is loaded. Documentation does not say how to form cofinguration array, whether they are needed or not, nothing. I believe that each extension which is intended for real use should have its own documentation page where any possible configuration parameters of the extension should be described.

Any ideas?

Comment: No one from autodesk has nothing to say to it?

Comment: for anyone new, the URL for v7 extension is this: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at the https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/library-javascript-viewer-extensions repo for more extension examples, along with usage instructions, but before that maybe review [this part](https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/viewer-javascript-tutorial/blob/master/chapters/chapter-3.md#Step3). Perhaps you missed something.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you I will take a look and try.

Comment: That repo is outdated. I know how to load extensions. I am using few of my own and they work without problem. Only problem I have are with those core extensions. I believe there might be need to include some other javascript containing core extension definition not mentioned in the documentation (there is absolutely always something important not mentioned).